# Как сделать фрейм адаптивным?

Tags: css

На сайт вставляется видео через фрейм с vimeo.
Ширина - 100%. Как задать ширину, чтобы при изменении
ширины окна высота видео менялась пропорционально?

Comment: Спасибо! Самый рабочий вариант.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно так. Давно известный метод. В бутстрапе используется

```css
.video {
  height: 0;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}

.video iframe {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="video">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

[Демо](http://jsfiddle.net/r2b0e5fj/)

UPD. Как это работает? `padding-bottom` указанный в процентах будет считаться относительно ширины блока. Т.е. Если `padding-bottom` будет `100%`, ну а `height: 0`, то общая высота будет равна ширине. Получится квадрат)

Comment: Спасибо. Можете пояснить величину паддинга? (padding-bottom: 56.25%;)

Comment: @Виктор Павлов, ширина видео * 0.5625 = высота видео, такой padding позволяет видеть всё видео по высоте и без пустоты внизу

Comment: @Виктор Павлов Дополню, как оно считается. Если видео 16/9, то 9/16*100 = 56.25. Также и с 4/3 - 3/4*100 = 75.